# Running the cmd in windows command line as admin

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, window

Am opening windows cmd.exe as administrator and executing an installer(just call installer.exe) and it runs fine. But if I open the cmd.exe in normal mode ( not as administrator) but run the command as user administrator ( `runas /profile /user:adminstrator installer.exe`) am not able to execute the installer successfully.

The installer unpacks certain files in c:\users\ dir. 
The error that I get is :

```
"Error running java -Dpython.console.encoding=UTF-8 -jar C:\users\<username>/tools/x.jar : Program ended with an error exit code. "
```

How can I solve this issue? Since am trying to automate executing this installer, opening the cmd.exe as admin is out of question. I would like to run the command as a normal user or if not possible, as an admin.

Am new to Windows. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: is java in the %path of the admin account?

Comment: Run a command, or create a batch script?

Comment: I checked the system environment variable. JAVA_HOME exists and is also included in Path. How do I check if java is in the path for admin and if its in path for other users? Also i checked C:\Program Files\Java\jdk ( JAVA_HOME). All admins had full access and regular users had only read access. I changed to full access for regular users as well. But still I see the same error.

Comment: @UnknownOctopus - I am trying to get the cmd to work successfully first. After it is done, I will create a .bat file with this one line cmd in it

Answer (score 1):

You could create the `.bat` file with the line you want to run, then follow the procedures listed below to have it automatically run as an administrator.

1. Right click on the original file and click Create shortcut.
2. Right click on the shortcut and select the `properties` option.
3. Under the `shortcut` tab, click on the `advanced` button in the bottom right hand corner.
4. Check the box that says *run as administrator*
5. Click *ok*, and then *ok*.

Now when you double click on the batch file shortcut it will run as an administrator. You can delete the original if you wish to.